# Is there any client side Db library that supports partial text search?

Tags: javascript, lovefield

I am going thru `IndexDB` or `lovefield` but so far could not find way to search partial text like we do in SQL queries via `LIKE`keyword. Can someone guide me how could it be achieved?

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._

Comment: fuse.js is a light-weight search index you could use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lovefield` has the `match`  function for pattern matching  which is similar to the `SIMILAR` keyword in SQL which inturn is similar to the `LIKE` keyword. Please have a look at it and see if it does the job

https://github.com/google/lovefield/blob/master/docs/spec/04_query.md